# Textbook confusion in 8-bit representation

Tags: computer-science, number-systems

A textbook I'm following says the following in the section **8-Bit Representation of a Number**:

"Now consider the two’s complement of an integer n that satisﬁes the inequality $1 \leq n \leq
128$.

Then,

$$− 1 \geq −n \geq− 128$$

and,

$$2^8 − 1 \geq 2^8 − n \geq 2^8 - 128 $$

But, $2^8 - 128 = 256 - 128 = 128 = 2^7$.

And therefore, $2^7 \leq$ the two's complement of n $ < 2^8$." ---------- (1)

Everything is fine up to here, but now the book drops the bombshell: "It follows that the 8-bit two’s complement of an integer from 1 through 128 has a leading bit of 1."

Well, I can convince myself that such is the case, but I don't see how that follows from result (1) above. My reasoning is as follows:

A number less than or equal to 128 takes 7 bits. This means representations from 0000000 to 1111111 are possible. In the last number, taking two's complement naturally gives a leading 1, while in the rest the existence of at least one 0 'absorbs' the carry within the 7-bit string itself, leaving the original bit unchanged after addition of 1 (which means, the original 0, which is now 1).

I, however, don't see why result (1) points to this. For instance, consider the sequence $2^7 + 1 = 1000001$. This is greater than $2^7$, but the 8-bit representation does **not** contain a leading one.

Please help!

Comment: You've made a mistake there: $2^7+1=10,000,000 + 1 = 10,000,001$, and does have a leading zero (commas don't mean anything here).  Also, it is generally true that an integer $n$ where $2^7 \leq n \leq 2^8-1$ will have a $1$ in the $2^7$'s place in its binary presentation. Is that the confusing bit here?

Comment: Ah! I see where I've overlooked the point. I was under the assumption that $2^7$ will involve 7 bits, whereas it uses all eight. Thank you!

Comment: Which book is this? In two's complement representation, the number $1$ is represented as $0000\,0001$ which has a leading $0$. Any number whose representation in two's complement has a leading $1$ is negative.

Comment: The book is Discrete Mathematics and Applications by Susanna S. Epp

Comment: The way I keep it straight is by remembering that $2^7$ has $7$ zeros in binary for the same reason that $10^7$ has $7$ zeros in decimal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just getting confused by an easy passage.

Recall $p^n$ in base $p$ is written as $1$ followed by $n$ zeros.
To always remember that, keep in mind this example from the familiar base $10$:
$10^2 = 100$  (exponent is 2 $\implies$ 2 zeros $\implies$ 3 digits).

So $2^7$ is written as $10000000$, a leading one followed by $7$ zeros: 8 bits. 
Its 8-bit representation starts with a $1$. 
And so does $2^7 + 1 = 10000001$

The textbook just gives it for granted that you know that, in base $p$, anything between $p^k$ (included) to $p^{(k+1)}$ (excluded) in base $p$ takes exactly $k+1$ digits with a non-zero leading digit.
For example, in the familiar base 10, everything between $10^1$ (included) and $10^2$ (excluded), i.e. everything from 10 to 99, takes 2 digits including the starting non-zero digit.

So from $2^7 \leq  k <2^8$ it does follow, naturally, that $k$ will be written, in base 2, with 8 digits starting with a non-zero digit.

Comment: Yes, that is where the confusion was. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $2^7+1=10000001_2$, but you cannot represent $129_{10}$ in eight bits of twos complement.  The largest positive number you can represent is $127_{10}=2^7-1=01111111_2$ which has a leading zero as claimed.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. My representation of $2^7 + 1$ contained seven bits, not eight. :)

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing of the book is a little confusing. When it says

> It follows that the 8-bit two’s complement of an integer from 1 through 128 has a leading bit of 1.

it does not mean that a number between 1 to 128 will have a leading digit of $1$ when written in $8$-bit two's complement. That makes no sense anyway, because $128$ cannot be written in $8$-bit two's complement.

What the book means is that if you take a number $n$ between $1$ and $128$ and take the mathematical two's complement, which means computing $m = 2^8 - n$, and then you write $m$ as an $8$-bit unsigned binary number, the result will have a leading digit of $1$. And that fact follows from the inequality $m = 2^8 -n \geq 2^8 - 128 \geq 128$, as the book says.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess it meant negative numbers with magnitude between 1 and 128.

Comment: It's a common difficulty with language: there is the "two's complement of a number", which is a mathematical operation that is not directly tied to binary representations, and then there is the "two's complement representation of a number" which is a particular binary representation. There are other binary representations, though, with "unsigned" also being very common. In the quoted passage, the book is using the two's complement operation and the unsigned representation, not the two's complement representation.

Comment: Very good point!

Comment: The book has kind of bluffed, I now realize. The early calculations involve subtracting from $2^8$, which would take 9 bits to represent, not eight. How I wish writers paid attention to these small details.